# How can I add labels to "deploy" through docker service create

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I usually create my stacks using docker-compose, but when I have a single service, I prefer to create it directly as a service, without the underlying (and useless) stack.

My problem is about the labels I need to set under the "deploy" sections, such as Traefik's ones :

```
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  labels:
   - "traefik.enable=true"
   - "traefik.gis.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/sig"
   - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/web"
   - "traefik.port=80"
   - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-network"
```

I don't know to set them through *docker service create* . This **will not work** , because Traefik requires that labels are set under deploy section:

```
docker service create \
    --name myService \
    --with-registry-auth \
    --network traefik-net \
    --label "traefik.enable=true" \
    --label "traefik.gis.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/sig" \
    --label "traefik.web.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/web" \
    --label "traefik.port=80" \
    --label "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net" \
    dvgerdrh2:5050/georeso/someImage:1.3.2
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why you don't use YML and `docker stack deploy...`?

Comment: I do, most of the time. But I would like learn how to do the same with docker service create.

Comment: Seems like you was on right way, but maybe mistake with double quotes. Look here on example in documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#set-metadata-on-a-service--l---label

Comment: Tried both way, but this didn't work the way I expect : I want the label to be related to "deploy". If I do it the way I tried, the label is associated with the service itself.. and not to the deploy part of it, leading to Traefik not being able to use it correctly

Comment: The deploy section defines the labels on the service, which is the cli option you used. You can also define labels one level up which makes a container label, which is a different cli option. Your syntax looks right for traefik configured for swarm mode.

Comment: hey @Marvin did you figure out a way to add the labels? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @tkyass no, never figured it out. I keep doint it in docker-compose

Comment: bummer .. I use stack deploy not compose so I don't know if I still need to place the labels under deploy section in the stack file?

Comment: I use stack deploy as well, with compose file :)

Answer (score -1):

Try --label traefik.enable=“true"

Think you have the quotes in the wrong place